# Test Class in Auto-populate

Tags: apex, test-setup

Hi can you help me build my Test Class? Below are my Apex Class and Test Class.

Apex Class

```
 public void autoPopulate(List<SObject> newList){
    System.debug('#####alignTaskSubCategory');
    List<Task> newListTask = (List<Task>) newList;
    Set <Id> setCaseIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Case> lstCase = new List<Case>();
    Map<Id, String> mapCaseCateg = new Map<Id, String>();
    
    for(Task t: newListTask){
        setCaseIds.add(t.WhatId);
    }
    
    System.debug('####setCaseIds: '+ setCaseIds);
    if(!setCaseIds.isEmpty()){
        for(Case c: [Select Id, Category__c, Subcategory__c FROM Case Where Id =:setCaseIds]){
            mapCaseCateg.put(c.Id, c.Category__c +' - '+c.Subcategory__c);
            
        }
        
    }
    
    System.debug('###mapCaseCateg: '+mapCaseCateg);
    if(!mapCaseCateg.isEmpty()){
        for(Task t: newListTask){
            if(t.Task_Category__c == null){
                
                t.Task_Category__c = mapCaseCateg.get(t.WhatId);
            }
        }
    }     
}
```

Test Class

```
 @isTest
public class testClass{   
    
    @testSetup
    static void setup(){
        
        Case c = new Case();
        c.Subject='Sample Test 1';
        c.Description='Sample Test 1 - Description' ;
        
        c.Status='New';
        insert c;
        
        Task t = new Task();
        t.ownerId = c.Id;
        t.whoId = c.Id;
        t.Subject = 'Run Test Trigger';
        t.Status = 'Not Started';
        t.Task_Category__c='';
        t.Priority = 'Normal';
        insert t;
    }
    
    @isTest
    static void testAutoPpulate(){
        Test.startTest();
        List<Task> taskList = [SELECT Id, ownerId, whoId, Task_Category__c FROM Task];
        if(!taskList.isEMpty()){
            apexClass getClass = new apexClass();
            getClass.autoPopulate(taskList); 

            try {
               
            } catch (DmlException e) {
                system.assertEquals(true, e.getMessage().contains('my expected error'));
            }
        }
        Test.stopTest();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: your try-catch block makes no sense -- you have nothing inside the try block - it should enclose the `getClass.autoPopulate(taskList)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the test data for Category__c, Subcategory__c fields in case record

current code:

```
Case c = new Case();
c.Subject='Sample Test 1';
c.Description='Sample Test 1 - Description' ;

c.Status='New';
insert c;
```

change to:

```
Case c = new Case();
c.Subject='Sample Test 1';
c.Description='Sample Test 1 - Description' ;
c.Category__c = 'Category value';
c.Subcategory__c ='Subcategory value'

c.Status='New';
insert c;
```